# Data grid not showing added records despite notification

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I'm adding instances to the list in view model as follows. Since the list is listened to but not the indivisual items, I realized that I need to tell the view explicitly that the list it's bound to, is updated.

```
public class ThingyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public List<Thingy> Thingies { get; set; }

  public void Register(Thingy thingy)
  {
    using (ServiceClient client = ...)
      client.Register(thingy);
    Thingies.Add(thingy);
    OnPropertyChanged("Thingies");
  }
  ...
}
```

The method *OnPropertyChanged* is the default implementation served by VS, which I'm using every elsewhere. Hence, I have no reasons to suspect any foul play there.

When I break the execution in my view right at the call to *Register* in the view model, I can clearly see in the data context that the new instance isn't in the list prior to the call. Likewise clearly I can see that it's in the data context after the operation's been carried out.

So, if the data context **does indeed** get the new instance and the notification is called on (yes, I've quadruple-checked the spelling), what can there be wrong still? Apparently I'm missing something but at this point, I can't see what that could be - I need a pointer or two.

```
<igDP:XamDataGrid Name="DataGrid"
                  DataSource="{Binding Path=Thingies}"
                  ...>
```

Comment: Could you share also xaml? Why your ThingyViewModel doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface?

Comment: @user2250152 Oh, it does implement it. I just cut it off when making the example. My bad - let me correct it pronto. The XAML won't tell us much, likely, because it binds properly at start. But I'll post a piece of that as well, of course. Give me a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use ObservableCollection for the Thingies property (your code is missing what collection it is...) that collection will notify itself when new items get added or removed from it and you don't have to call any OnPropertyChange. And you don't want to notify that a as you are any way, as it is now you trying to tell the ui that Thingies is a new object and that isn't true, only the content of it has change.
And it this doesn't work you have to show us your XAML code too.

Comment: Good eyes on the missing type. Corrected the typo - thanks. However, my requirement is that I'm not always refreshing the view, so I can't use the *ObservableCollection* straight off. I need to be able to control when the notification is being delivered... (I know, unusual case...)

Comment: Can you use two collections, On that is what is shown on the UI (ObservableCollection) and an other "Queue" for what is added but not yet addet to the view? and WHEN you wanna do that you just loop throuh the queue and remove it from there and add it to the UI-collection?

Comment: This'll work just fine. Accepting the answer and +1 for the eyes spotting the typo.